# AWS IAM CDK: tagging and creating access key for a user

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use AWS CDK to create a user with minimal permissions through a custom policy, but I'm stuck with tagging that user and creating its access keys.

Below there's my code:

```js
    public class Sample extends App {
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
                App app = new App();
                new UserStack(app, "user-stack");
                app.run();
        }

        public static class UserStack extends Stack {
            // Not able to add Tag and Create Access Key
            public UserStack(final App parent, final String name) {
                super(parent, name);

                PolicyStatement statement = new PolicyStatement(
                    PolicyStatementEffect.Allow
                );
                statement.addResource("*");
                statement.addAction("lambda:UpdateFunctionCode");
                
                User user = new User(this, "LambdaDeployer",
                    UserProps.builder()
                    .withUserName("lambda-deployer")
                    .withPath("/").build()
                );
                user.addToPolicy(statement);
                
                Tag tag = new Tag("Project", "devops");
                // how to tag the user ??
                
                new CfnOutput(this, "LambdaDeployerOutputAccessKey",
                    CfnOutputProps.builder()
                    .withValue("AWS::IAM::AccessKey")
                    .build()
                );
                new CfnOutput(this, "LambdaDeployerOutputSecretAccessKey",
                    CfnOutputProps.builder()
                    .withValue("AWS::IAM::SecretAccessKey")
                    .build()
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/java/software/amazon/awscdk/services/cloudformation/CustomResource.html) in order to call the [`TagUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_TagUser.html) API, since adding tags to a User is [not available natively in CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user.html).

You can use a new feature in the CDK to help you author your Custom Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/pull/1850